# PHPMyAdmin MySQL syntax error when i create function

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

i was create a function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION diskon(
hrg_brg int,
jum_beli int
) RETURNS int
BEGIN
DECLARE diskon int;
DECLARE total_hrg int;
  
  SET total_hrg = jum_beli * hrg_brg;
  if jum_beli > 10 then 
  set diskon=0.1 * total_hrg;
  ELSE
  set diskon=0;
  end if;
  RETURN diskon;
END
```

but there is an error like this

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: You don't a[[ear to be setting delimiters see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html